# Converting ArcGIS Pro stylx to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, style

I have an ArcGIS Pro (.stylx) style I wish to convert to use in QGIS 3.10.

Is there a way to do this?

SLYR only allows ArcGIS (.style) and not (.stylx) from what I can see.

Comment: "We also have plans to extend SLYR to support the newer ArcGIS Pro LYRX and MAPX formats, and expect this functionality to be implemented during 2020."  https://north-road.com/slyr/ (bottom of page)

Comment: that doesn't answer the question and lyr files are different stlyx and style files.